# How to make Git automatically retain committer date for `git commit --amend`?

Tags: git, date, git-commit, git-amend

I am aware of Git picking up the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variable, but for every amending commit, I have to manually prepend `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git log -1 --pretty=tformat:%cD HEAD)"` to the command line. Is there a config option to make this behavior the default? Or can a wrapper script modify the behavior for `git-commit`? (I am not interested in creating a custom subcommand for Git, like `git amend`.)

Comment: I'm curious what the use case is for this. In my experience having a different committer date rarely ever matters, but every once in a while the extra information contained in the new committer date is helpful. I've never once wished the extra information wasn't there though...

Comment: @TTT Just personal aesthetic preference.

Comment: Note if you can change the behavior of `git-commit`, unless you are inspecting the command line options to isolate "amend", then the committer date will also be faked for `cherry-pick` and `rebase`, and not just `amend`. Not sure if you want that or not?

Comment: @TTT I need it to work for the `commit --amend` command-and-argument combination. Other commands may be affected or not - I don't care.